# Append suffix to build number for features branches in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

We version our builds with the following build number format:

`1.0$(rev:.r)`

In this way we can manually change major and minor version, but leave patch version incrementing:

```
1.0.1
1.0.2
...
```

However we would like to have a suffix appended to the build number format, so that if you queue build from a non master branch (e.g. feature branch, testing, hotfix), then you get a suffix (e.g. `-beta`, `-rc`, `-preview`). So we could have the following builds:

```
1.0.3
1.0.4-rc
1.0.5
...
```

This way it is easy for us to read from a version number if something is not coming from master, and care should be taken when deploying this version.

Is it possible to write an expression in the build number format so a string is suffixed if e.g `$(SourceBranchName)` is not empty?

Comment: I must add that I'm interested in changing not only the artifact build number, but the actual build number that is on the build.

When we use 'Releases', the 'Release name format' will include the build number as well. So I cannot see in 'Releases' whether something was originally made from an experimental feature branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append `$(SourceBranchName)` in build number format, but can’t append other content per to `$(SourcebranchName)` through build number format directly, in other words, no conditions available in build number format.

Refer to these steps to do it:

Add a PowerShell task (Inline Script):

```
$v=$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
if($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME -ne "master")
{
   $v="$v-rc"
}
Write-Host $v
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion;]$v"
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$v"
```

Change **Automatic package versioning** to **Use an environment variable** for NuGet pack or dotnet pack task, and specify **packageVersion** in Environment variable input box.

Comment: That is a good suggestion! However that won't affect the build number I see inside VSTS. When we use 'Releases', the 'Release name format' will include the build number as well. So I cannot see in 'Releases' whether something was originally made from an experimental feature branch.

Comment: @mbp Just update the build number through  Logging Command too (`Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$v"`) Check the update of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitVersion to do it. Install it from the marketplace:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion

Take a look [here](https://semver.org/) to understand how semantic versioning works.

You can learn more [here](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

This is a great tool to version your builds.

Comment: That is a good suggestion! However that won't affect the build number I see inside VSTS. When we use 'Releases', the 'Release name format' will include the build number as well. So I cannot see in 'Releases' whether something was originally made from an experimental feature branch.